# I want to take the output of Get-PSDrive to get the drive letter of all drives and do a search for ISO's and use the path from the Get-PSDrive

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use `Get-PSDrive` to put all the drive letters used by disks into a string that returns each letter (That works)

I am having problems using the `$ISODeviceLetter` variable to use it as a path to search all drives for *.ISO* files.

```
$ISODeviceLetter = Get-PSDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' | Select-String -Pattern '^[a-z]:$'

$ISOLocation = Get-ChildItem -Path $ISODeviceLetter -Recurse -Include *.ISO
```

This is the error I get:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Administrator\C' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:16
+ ... OLocation = Get-ChildItem -Path $ISODeviceLetter -Recurse -Include *. ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Administrator\C:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I see by the error the `get-childitem` is using the default location which is the *C:\Users\Administrator*.

The desired output is to pass `$ISODriveLetter` as the Path for all drives on the server "C:","D:","E:", so all the drives can be searched for *.ISO* files.

Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when referencing drives, they have to be distinguished using a colon (`:`) to disambiguate the drive from a regular folder/file:

- Use the `Foreach-Object` command to append the Colon to each drive letter returned.
- Changed the filter from `-Include` to `-Filter`, to speed up the process as `-Filter` is implemented by the [FileSystemProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_filesystem_provider?view=powershell-7.2), and you're also not looking for multiple files.
- Added `-File` switch for a more efficient query as well, since an *.ISO* extension is associated to a file.

```
$ISODeviceLetter = [array](Get-PSDrive | 
    Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -match "^.$"}).Foreach{
        $_.Name + ':'
    }

$ISOLocation = Get-ChildItem -Path $ISODeviceLetter -File -Recurse -Filter *.ISO
```

**Bonus**:
You can use Simplified Syntax to achieve the same results as above for better readability:

```
$ISODeviceLetter = (Get-PSDrive).Where{$_.Name -match "^.$"} | 
    Select -exp Name | Foreach Insert -ArgumentList 1,':'
```

---

*Only real "downside" of this is, that you're using the pipeline even more. Even though it may not affect the speed in your return for this example, other time sensitive tasks can take quite a performance hit using the pipeline.*

Comment: @ChristianJohnson, cool beans. See my update btw!

Comment: Nice, though it's worth pointing out that `Get-PSDrive -Name ?` is the simplest way to find all single-letter drive names. If you're in the mood for code golf: `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.ISO  -LiteralPath (Get-PSDrive ?).Name.Insert(1, ':')`

Comment: @mklement0, no way! I didn't know about that lol nice to know:). Gonna guess it's a wildcard expression?

Comment: Yes, `?` is a wildcard expression matching a single character. The `-Name` parameters of many cmdlets accept wildcards.

Comment: @mklement, wasn't aware of that. I usually go off the help when it says that it doesn't accept wildcards, but I'm guessing it means a literal asterisk that it doesn't accept? Is there an easy way to tell what does and doesn't accept wildcard expressions?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, unfortunately, the help is clearly incorrect in this case, and even programmatically there is currently no reliable way to detect wildcard support - there is a `SupportsWildcards` attribute, but it is only informational, and not consistently used. There are two relevant GitHub issues: [#4715](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4715) and [#4716](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4716).

Comment: @mklement0, man, you've come across every issue already lol i'm just surprised a solution still hasn't been implemented.